# LINQ Query Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have the following code in which I have declared a variable `groupLabel` and initialize it with `ObjectContext.Group_Label`, where `Group_Label` is a table.

I want to insert data into this variable from two tables and also want to check a condition `Group_Label_Delivery_Label` flag column have set. If not then only I want to add that record to `groupLabel`:

```
var groupLabel
    = ObjectContext.Group_Label
                   .Include("Group_Label_Delivery_Label")                  
                   .Include("Group_Label_Delivery_Label.Delivery_Label")
                   .FirstOrDefault(
                       gl => (!gl.is_delete)
                          && (gl.group_label_id == groupLabelId)
                          && (gl.owner_id == product.owner_id));
```

Please help me to check whether `Group_Label_Delivery_Label` have not set value of flag.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your tables have the correct foreign keys, and this is represented within your `.edmx` entity framework file, you should simply be able to call it within your lambda expression on the `FirstOrDefault()` call.

```
var groupLabel = ObjectContext.Group_Label
                     .Include("Group_Label_Delivery_Label")
                     .Include("Group_Label_Delivery_Label.Delivery_Label")
                     .FirstOrDefault(gl => (!gl.is_delete)
                         && (gl.group_label_id == groupLabelId)
                         && (gl.owner_id == product.owner_id)
                         && (!gl.Group_Label_Delivery_Label.IsDeleted);
```

Comment: I was not able to access IsFlagged column....it showing option like where, Union,List etc.

Comment: Could you possibly post your class structure please? :)

Comment: I want to also know that if i have used FirstOrDefault in my LINQ query then how could it retrieving two records.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` will return, as it suggests, the `First` record, or `null` if none exist. You may want to consider using the `Take(x)` method if you want to specify the number of results.

Comment: following are the tables :                    dbo.Group_Label_Delivery_Label( group_label_id pk,Delivery_label_id pk,is_delete,entry_date )                             dbo.Group_Label( group_label_id pk,name, is_delete,entry_date)                                     i want record which have not set Group_Label_Delivery_Label tables is_delete column to True.

Comment: But when i debug this query and check the value of groupLabel variable then it showing two records...then how it possible if i used FirstOrDefault

Comment: `groupLabel` will only be a single record, but it may have multiple children. Are you trying to select the `Group_Label` or one of it's children?

Comment: Where is the FK constraint? is `group_label_id` a FK in `Group_Label_Delivery_Label`?, edit: How does this look?